# Can't replace MOVW / MOVT with LDR

Tags: stm32, cortex-m, thumb

I want to replace this `movw / movt` combination with a single `ldr` instruction:

```
movw r0, #0x3800
movt r0, #0x4002

      |
      V

ldr r0, =0x40023800
```

However, after this change the code no longer works. Since this is the only part I changed, it must be at fault. I was under the impression that those two code segments are identical.

The assembly code has the following instructions at the top

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb
```

and is compiled using the [GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) with the following commands:

```
arm-none-eabi-as -mcpu=cortex-m4 code.s -c -o code.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -T link.ld -nostartfiles -o result code.o
```

In case it matters, the remainder of the code is identical to the one hosted at [this page](https://mcla.ug/blog/how-to-flash-an-led.html) (at the bottom). The code is running on an STM32F411CEU6 with an Arm Cortex-M4 core.

Why does this change break my code? Is there an alternative one-line method for writing a 32bit immediate value to a register?

---

Running an `objdump` on the assembler result shows this (note the beginning of `<main>` and the end of `<loop>`:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   4810        ldr r0, [pc, #64]   ; (44 <.loop+0x2a>)
   2:   f240 0101   movw    r1, #1
                 [removed]
  18:   6001        str r1, [r0, #0]

0000001a <.loop>:
  1a:   f240 0100   movw    r1, #0
                 [removed]
  44:   40023800    andmi   r3, r2, r0, lsl #16
```

Comment: Have a look at the assembled assembler. Preferably in a debugger so you can see what is happening. LDR (load immediate) is a pseudo instruction so the assembler should replace it with the real instruction(s). The way ARM encodes the immediate value is not straight forward. I am surprised that the assembler has not given you a warning.

Comment: @RealtimeRik I don't have access to a debugger, but I did add an objdump to the question.

Comment: @KevinKevinski it is correctly translated - see my answer. ARM instruction set was not designed for humans only compilers. Programming in assembler makes almost no sense except maybe some very low level core related stuff (like context switching in the supervisor handler)

Comment: Yeah, the code seems to be correct, and so it should load the register with the proper value.  Unless you are able to prove, with your debugger or otherwise, that the wrong value is actually being loaded, I would suspect that the problem is somewhere else, and just happened to be triggered by this unrelated change.

Comment: @NateEldredge especially if the fault is imprecise.

Comment: @KevinKevinski Get yourself a cheap ST Nucleo STM32F4 board with a similar processor. It includes a ST-Link debugger. Less than £20.

Answer (score 0):

First off, assembly language is specific to the assembler (armasm, gas, etc) not the target (cortex-m4), they can be and certainly often are incompatible languages across tools.  Ldr is often used as a pseudo instruction, meaning the assembler decides what instruction(s) to use for you rather than the one you asked for.

```
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb

ldr r0,=0x12345678
ldr r1,=0x00000003
ldr r2,=0xFFFFFFF5
nop
nop
b .
```

assemble and disassemble

```
00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <.text+0x10>)
   2:   f04f 0103   mov.w   r1, #3
   6:   f06f 020a   mvn.w   r2, #10
   a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   c:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   e:   e7fe        b.n e <.text+0xe>
  10:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

Using gnu assembler first and foremost the ldr r0,= syntax is supported, do not expect all arm/thumb assemblers to support that syntax.  Second, with gnu assembler (and perhaps others as pointed out in another answer), if the tool can create an optimization that does not actually do an ldr, it will.

We can see that for the second and third constants the assembler used non-load instructions with the constant embedded as an immediate.

For the 0x12345678 value, you simply cannot fit 32 bits of immediate into a 32 bit (or 16 bit) instruction, you have to make a load, and it does it by finding a pool to put the constant in and making a pc-relative load to it.

Assembly language is most definitely not for compilers, only some compilers use assembly language anyway.  We would not have the current nor new processors without assembly language to be used, by humans, for processor development and testing.  So non-human asm would mean no processors.  We would not be able to bootstrap high level programming languages, so there would be no programming languages.  There would be no compilers because you need individuals well versed in the instruction set via assembly language (even if the compiler does not compile to asm) in order to be able to successfully create a compiler, so there would be no compilers, which there were not already for other reasons.  If human instruction set level programming goes away, processors and all the side effects go away.  Many people each generation have to carry the torch and find and teach others.

I got lucky (well, it was planned), the work is not done here, what about this:

```
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb

ldr r0,=0x12345678
ldr r1,=0x00000003
ldr r2,=0xFFFFFFF5
nop
b .

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <.text+0x10>)
   2:   f04f 0103   mov.w   r1, #3
   6:   f06f 020a   mvn.w   r2, #10
   a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   c:   e7fe        b.n c <.text+0xc>
   e:   56780000    ldrbtpl r0, [r8], -r0
  12:   Address 0x0000000000000012 is out of bounds.
```

The constant was placed on a non-word aligned boundary.  It may have assembled successfully but the ldr is an unaligned transfer which may cause an exception and the code won't work.

Quick fix:

```
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb

ldr r0,=0x12345678
ldr r1,=0x00000003
ldr r2,=0xFFFFFFF5
nop
b .
.align


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <.text+0x10>)
   2:   f04f 0103   mov.w   r1, #3
   6:   f06f 020a   mvn.w   r2, #10
   a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   c:   e7fe        b.n c <.text+0xc>
   e:   bf00        nop
  10:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
```

And that worked.  We are still running on assumptions as to where the pool will go, we can try to force it.

```
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb

one:
ldr r0,=0x12345678
ldr r1,=0x00000003
ldr r2,=0xFFFFFFF5
b .
.align

two:
ldr r0,=0x11223344
b .
.align

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <one>:
   0:   4803        ldr r0, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <two+0x4>)
   2:   f04f 0103   mov.w   r1, #3
   6:   f06f 020a   mvn.w   r2, #10
   a:   e7fe        b.n a <one+0xa>

0000000c <two>:
   c:   4801        ldr r0, [pc, #4]    ; (14 <two+0x8>)
   e:   e7fe        b.n e <two+0x2>
  10:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
  14:   11223344            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x11223344


.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb

one:
ldr r0,=0x12345678
ldr r1,=0x00000003
ldr r2,=0xFFFFFFF5
b .
.align
.ltorg

two:
ldr r0,=0x11223344
b .
.align

00000000 <one>:
   0:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (c <one+0xc>)
   2:   f04f 0103   mov.w   r1, #3
   6:   f06f 020a   mvn.w   r2, #10
   a:   e7fe        b.n a <one+0xa>
   c:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000

00000010 <two>:
  10:   4800        ldr r0, [pc, #0]    ; (14 <two+0x4>)
  12:   e7fe        b.n 12 <two+0x2>
  14:   11223344            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x11223344
```

The pc relative load is in a positive direction, so we didn't completely control this:

```
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb

one:
ldr r0,=0x12345678
ldr r1,=0x00000003
ldr r2,=0xFFFFFFF5
nop
b .

two:
ldr r0,=0x11223344
b .
.align
.ltorg


00000000 <one>:
   0:   4804        ldr r0, [pc, #16]   ; (14 <two+0x6>)
   2:   f04f 0103   mov.w   r1, #3
   6:   f06f 020a   mvn.w   r2, #10
   a:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   c:   e7fe        b.n c <one+0xc>

0000000e <two>:
   e:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (18 <two+0xa>)
  10:   e7fe        b.n 10 <two+0x2>
  12:   bf00        nop
  14:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
  18:   11223344            ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x11223344
```

We do not need to have the align before two, two can land on a non-32 bit boundary so we save a halfword there sometimes.  The .align (assembly language is specific to the assembler, not the target, this is language supported by gnu assembler and does a specific thing for this target) allows it to align on a 4 byte boundary so the ldr will not fault, and .ltorg which does not actually change things here, just indicates this is where we want. You also have to be knowledgeable about how far a pc-relative load can work, each instruction set (arm, mips, x86, etc) the range varies so you cannot just stick a pool way at the end of a big project.

Why does this not necessarily work for you?  We need to see and understand - did you simply change the assembly language and re-assemble or did you hack in to the binary some instruction?  The latter has a lot of problems including instruction size as well as how you shim in an item into the pool.  If it is just code and you assembled it it may very well be unaligned and you may be getting an unaligned access fault.

But ldr rd,= can cover all possible bit patterns, and movw/movt can as well. But the ldr rd,= on gnu assembler optimizes if it can otherwise it needs the pool and the pool needs to be ready for it.  Where if you create movw/movt by hand all you need are those two instructions, no pool.

You need to make a more complete example and define what "no longer works" means.

Comment: external links in questions or answers can go stale and are not maintained in parallel with these pages, better to cut and paste that code into the question.  I normally never look at the links on principle but did in this case and if you disassemble I suspect you simply have an alignment problem, and perhaps a single .align at the bottom will fix it.  but you have to try it

Answer (score -1):

`ldr` is a pseudo instruction that translates to load from the pool.

> The `LDR Rd,=const` pseudo-instruction generates the most efficient
> single instruction to load any 32-bit number. You can use this
> pseudo-instruction to generate constants that are out of range of the
> MOV and MVN instructions. The LDR pseudo-instruction generates the
> most efficient single instruction for the specified immediate value:
>
> If the immediate value can be constructed with a single MOV or MVN instruction, the assembler generates the appropriate instruction.
> If the immediate value cannot be constructed with a single MOV or MVN instruction, the assembler:
> Places the value in a literal pool (a portion of memory embedded in the code to hold constant values).
> Generates an LDR instruction with a PC-relative address that reads the constant from the literal pool.
> For example:
>
> ```
>     LDR      rn, [pc, #offset to literal pool]
>                           ; load register n with one word
>                           ; from the address [pc + offset]
> ```
>
> You must ensure that there is a literal pool within range of the LDR instruction generated by the assembler.

https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731147386.htm